# Order by makes slow mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

it took us 5 sec to load but when i remove ORDER BY it took us only 0.4 sec any ideas on improve this query?

the below query has more left join too but don't think it's not a issue

```
SELECT b.id, 
  b.name, 
  b.start_date, 
  b.start_time, 
  at.filename, 
  at.width, 
  at.height, 
  at.id   AS attachment_id, 
  ve.name AS venue_name, 
  ve.slug AS v_slug, 
  ve.address, 
  ci.name AS city_name, 
  st.code AS state_code 
FROM   events b 
LEFT JOIN attachments at 
    ON at.foreign_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN venues ve 
    ON b.venue_id = ve.id 
LEFT JOIN cities ci 
    ON ve.city_id = ci.id 
LEFT JOIN states st 
    ON ci.state_id = st.id 
WHERE  1 = 1 
  AND b.start_date >= '2016-10-06' 
  AND b.is_active = 1 
  AND b.virtual_delete = 0 
  AND ve.is_approved = 1 
GROUP  BY b.id 
ORDER  BY b.event_view_count DESC 
LIMIT  30
```

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on the query, and if you don't have an index on `events.event_view_count`, then consider adding one.

Comment: `WHERE  1 = 1 ` - What is this???

Comment: events.event_view_count is indexed and everything in where condition is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html).

> To increase ORDER BY speed, check whether you can get MySQL to use indexes rather than an extra sorting phase.

So first of all check if `event_view_count` column indexed.

Comment: event_view_count is indexed but after indexing also it makes slow

Comment: what if you remove `DESC` from `order by`? Will it became faster?

Comment: it took same 5secs even after removing DESC from ORDER BY. we have added index for the fields in where condition.